# is there any way to debug android app on device while using remote desktop

Tags: android-studio, debugging, adb, remote-debugging, remote-desktop

As I and most of us WFH nowadays I am curious to know if there is way we can debug android app using remote AS and device connected to local machine.
I am using my laptop to connect my work machine which is super fast compare to my laptop so I want that device connected to my laptop is accessible by AS running in my work machine(Remote desktop).

I tried enabling usb port sharing while connecting to work system with remote desktop but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes in fact there is, I had the same problem as you, I was WFH but my Remote machine was unable to detect devices plugged into my laptop at home through Windows Remote Desktop (both machines Windows 10).

After searching for a long time I found the following the guide here: https://workspot.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/214248563-Configuring-USB-Redirection-with-RemoteFX-in-Workspot

It requires you to Edit the Group Policy on both machines to allow USB Redirection with RemoteFX.

After following the instructions, I was able to detect the devices on my Remote Machine and all worked perfectly through Android Studio on the Remote Machine.

After rebooting both machines and connecting the RDP, make sure to enable the device to be shared on the RDP session using the bar at the top with a Printer icon, there you can tick to enable the device.